# MySQL Random unique precent data from table with 1 column (without primary key)

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I need take data from a table (100% of all data) and split it to 3 columns.

Example: We have data:

```
numbers
80174
91467
1105
12040
62224
46508
33149
61384
10811
84923
```

We need to take:

```
      | Random 60% of all | Random  40% of all
      | unique and not    | unique and not 
  All | contained in 40%  | contained in 60% 
      | of the column     | of the column
----------------------------------------------
80174 |      84923        |      33149
91467 |      91467        |      61384
1105  |       1105        |      10811
12040 |      62224        |      80174
62224 |      12040        |     
46508 |      46508        |     
33149 |                   |
61384 |                   |
10811 |                   |
84923 |                   |
```

Comment: is there a need ti have them in one result set?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This uses the ORDER BY RAND() function to randomize a the rows
ANd it uses the mysql 8 window function ROW_NUMBER to split first the number in to 60/40 and after that to join them.

you can rebuild the row_number function in mysql 5.x but it isn't as pretty

Edit after torpas advice, calculate the number of necessary rows.
Edit 2: after another comment from forpas i replaced CEIL with RAND

I think there must be a refined solution where the is more use  of the MODULO

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`numbers` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`numbers`)
> VALUES
>     (80174),
>     (91467),
>     (1105),
>     (12040),
>     (62224),
>     (46508),
>     (33149),
>     (61384),
>     (10811),
>     (84923),
>     (80179),
>     (91469),
>     (1109),
>     (12049),
>     (62229)    
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH rand_num as (SELECT `numbers`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) as rn FROM Table1 ),
> limitscal as (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*)  * 6 / 10),0)  si_x  FROM Table1),
> countcal as (SELECT COUNT(*)  cnt  FROM Table1),
> 60_num as (SELECT `numbers`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) as rn2 
>             FROM  rand_num CROSS JOIN limitscal CROSS JOIN countcal
>             WHERE rn MOD countcal.cnt < limitscal.si_x)
> ,40_num as (SELECT `numbers`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) as rn2 
>             FROM  rand_num CROSS JOIN limitscal  CROSS JOIN countcal 
>             WHERE rn MOD countcal.cnt >= limitscal.si_x )
> SELECT 6_n.`numbers`,4_n.`numbers` FROM 60_num 6_n LEFT JOIN 40_num 4_n ON 6_n.rn2 = 4_n.rn2
> ```

> ```
> numbers | numbers
> ------: | ------:
>   10811 |   61384
>   80174 |   12049
>   12040 |   46508
>   91467 |   84923
>   80179 |    1109
>   91469 |   62224
>   33149 |    null
>    1105 |    null
>   62229 |    null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdb066280f29751a2d6997240f6d6a7a)*

Comment: @forpas you are right, i changed it that it allows any number of rows

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a grouping based on `rand()`:

```
select t.*, (case then rand() < 0.6 then 1 else 2 end) as grouping
from t;
```

Note that this is *approximately* 60%/40%.  If you want an exact split, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum <= 0.6 * cnt then 1 else 2 end) as grouping
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: If window functions are available, it is easier to use `NTILE()`. For 60% it will be `NTILE(5) <= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to number your rows randomly. And you want to do this twice. Once for the random split into 60% and 40%, once for the random ordering of all columns.

As of MySQL 8 you can use the window function `ROW_NUMBER` for this. Applying this twice as `row_number() over (order by rand())`, however, leads to the same random order twice, because MySQL sees that you order by the same expression. So, change the expression slightly, e.g. by adding two different constants.

The rest is two outer joins to the 100% rows, one to join the 60%, one to join the remaining 40%.

```
with prepared as
(
  select
    number,
    row_number() over (order by rand() + 0) as rn1,
    row_number() over (order by rand() + 1) as rn2,
    count(*) over () as cnt
  from numbers
)
, p100 as (select rn1 as rn, number from prepared)
, p60 as (select rn2 as rn, number from prepared where rn2 / cnt <= 0.6)
, p40 as (select cnt - rn2 + 1 as rn, number from prepared where rn2 / cnt > 0.6)
select
  p100.number as number1,
  p60.number as number2,
  p40.number as number3
from p100
left join p60 on p60.rn = p100.rn
left join p40 on p40.rn = p100.rn
order by p100.rn;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b14419fd15f8a7987c10f2ef25ced826